# Find all roots of the polynomial $x^5-5x^3-20x+a^2$, if this polynomial has real root of multiplicity 2

Tags: polynomials

I want to find all roots of the polynomial $x^5-5x^3-20x+a^2$, if this polynomial has real root of multiplicity 2.

I usually know how to find roots of polynomials if multiplicity of a root is known, but here the constant is $a^2$, and that's what confuses me.
If I start with $p/q$ as a rational root, $p|a^2$ and $q|1$, and then try with 1, -1, 2, -2 as possible roots. I don't know what to do with $a^2$.

Comment: When you perform polynomial division, $\frac{x^5 - 5x^3 - 20 x + a^2}{(x-b)^2}$, the quotient is the polynomial $x^3 + 2bx^2 + \cdots$ and the remainder is $a^2 + 10b^3 - 4b^5 + (\text{quartic in $b$})x$.  For $b$ to be a double root, that remainder is zero, so you get two relations: the constant term in the remainder relates $a^2$ and $b$ and the linear term in the remainder is a quadratic in $b^2$ (and you know how to solve quadratics).  Then, for each choice of pairs $a$ and $b$, the (cubic) quotient gives the other three roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

If the proposed polynomial has a root of multiplicity two, such root is also a root of its first derivative.

Hence we conclude it must correspond to one of the following values:
\begin{align*}
5x^{4} - 15x^{2} - 20 = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow x^{4} - 3x^{2} - 4 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x^{2} - \frac{3}{2}\right)^{2} - \frac{9}{4} - 4 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x^{2} - \frac{3}{2}\right)^{2} = \frac{25}{4}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - \frac{3}{2} = \pm\frac{5}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} = 4)\vee(x^{2} = - 1) 
\end{align*}

Given that we are interested in real roots, we can discard the last possibility.

Having said that, you are able to find out the possible values of $a$.

Can you take it from here?